# json object index start at 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a PHP file where I start my `array` index at 1 as shown in the below code snippet.

In my AngularJS app, I am using the `$http.post` to get the JSON data, the weird thing is that my JavaScript JSON object starts at 0, but my PHP array starts at 1.

Is it because when I JSON encode, the indexing gets lost?

In the below screenshot my JSON object index starts at 0 which is throwing off the order of my posts. Is there a way to set index of the JSON object to 1 in AngularJS?

The reason being is that I use a date filter to match the post id to the computer date (`dayNumber` variable), so for instance: today is the 14th but the post that I get is the 15th. I could do dayNumber -1 so I can adjust the day number but I would like to try and learn something new. Anyone please?

**PHP File code snippet:**

```php
$arr = array();

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[] = $row;  
    }
}

//sort obj to start from ASC
sort($arr);

$iOne = array_combine(range(1, count($arr)), array_values($arr));

# JSON-encode the response

$iOne = array_values($iOne);

$json_response1 = json_encode($iOne);

//$json_response = json_encode($arr);

// # Return the response
echo $json_response1;

**AngularJS code snippet:**

app.controller('TimeController', function($scope, $filter, $http) {
  $http.post('ajax/getQuotes.php').success(function(data){

      console.log(data);

     $scope.quote = data;
  });
  $scope.dayNumber = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'd');
console.log( $scope.dayNumber);
```

**Output (in the console):**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$iOne = array_values($iOne);
```

is "reseting" the indices.

Try without this line or is there a reason you need this?

**EDIT**

If you need numeric indices the easiest way would be adding a dummy value at position 0 (in php). With that you can skip the $iOne stuff:

```
array_unshift($arr, null);
$json_response1 = json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The reason that I am using this is that my json was a string meaning it starts the array with: {"1":{"id":"1","quote": so when I used this function it turns my string into a json object like so: [{"id":"1","quote":...

Comment: I'm afraid you can't have numeric indices in JavaScript that don't start at 0. So maybe try the code in my edit...

Answer (score 0):

Starting an array from the index 1 is not a good practice. That courses memory waste. What I suggest is to change your

```
dayNumber
```

to

```
dayNumber -1
```

Otherwise your code will get complicated with its flow.